# Missing file R.java when creating ZXing library for my app

Tags: java, android, zxing

I'm trying to add the QR scan to my android app. I already know that it's advised to use the Intent method, but the app it's a university project and, therefore, we need to integrate it.

So, I downloaded the pre builded `core.jar` and the Zxing sources (version 3.0.1), then I created a new Android project with the files in `zxing-zxing-3.0.1/android`, and then added the `core.java` in the `libs` folder and in the build path.

Basically I'm at step 5 of [this](http://techiedreams.com/android-zxing-barcode-scanner-integration/) guide.

The problem is this: my errors do not disappears because the file R.java do not shows up.

I'm using the Android Developing Tools with Eclipse.

Comment: Check for errors in your XML files..

Comment: "the app it's a university project and, therefore, we need to integrate it" -- university students installed *your* app somehow. Installing Barcode Scanner is no harder. The `IntentIntegrator` code will even lead the user to the right entry in the Play Store for you.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. It's not a commercial project, no one outside our team's members and the professor will ever install the app and the professor clearly stated, when asked, that we had to integrate the scanner in the app. I understand the reasons why it's not advised doing so but we cannot go against what our prof said.

Answer (score 0):

`R.java` is generated by the Android SDK build tools. You didn't build the project yet.

Comment: But Eclipse will not let me run the project with those errors. I feel like I'm missing something but I'm very new to the whole Android developing.

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

- look for errors in your layout XML-files
- clean your project

Comment: I already corrected some errors in the layouts (two buttons were missing), What do you mean with clean the project?

Comment: @Higure: In Eclipse, Project > Clean from the main menu. `R.java` not being generated means that there is an error in a resource or in the manifest. If you cannot find the error via the red icons in Package Explorer, open up the Errors view in Eclipse and see what is listed there.